# How can I extract bonus images from a tv show DVD using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, dvd

I'm using [MakeMKVcon](https://www.makemkv.com/developers/usage.txt) to automate episodes extraction. It do the job, expect the metadata. I have to rename files manually. But the problem here is that I want to extract some bonus pictures slideshow from the ISO but no software can detect it. I can only display those images using VLC (using the ISO file).

Do you have any idea how to do that ?

Here's the `ffmpeg -i` output:

```sh
$ ffmpeg -i /path/to/iso/file.ISO
ffmpeg version git-2020-03-24-7239254 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/HEAD-7239254_1 --enable-shared --cc=clang --host-cflags=-fno-stack-check --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-htmlpages --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56. 42.101 / 56. 42.101
  libavcodec     58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavformat    58. 42.100 / 58. 42.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.100 /  7. 77.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[mpeg @ 0x7f8111808200] Packet corrupt (stream = 4, dts = 2097152).
[mpeg @ 0x7f8111808200] stream 4 : no TS found at start of file, duration not set
[mpeg @ 0x7f8111808200] Could not find codec parameters for stream 4 (Audio: mp2, 0 channels): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpeg, from '/path/to/iso/file.ISO':
  Duration: 00:24:21.47, start: 0.280000, bitrate: 40817 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 8000000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:2[0x20]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
    Stream #0:3[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:4[0x1d7]: Audio: mp2, 0 channels
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Did you try `ffmpeg -i file.iso output.mkv`?

Comment: yes but only the episodes and the dvd intro is extracted.